# Access installation folder from cli in bash package

Tags: bash, shell-script, package-management

I am creating a package (weffe) written purely in bash containing an executable and static files the script needs to access. However, I would like this script to be able to be run with local files if the package is cloned with git or if it's installed to `/usr/bin/weffe` with data in the `/usr/share/weffe` folder. If the package is run from the command line, e.g. if `weffe` is run on a terminal, is there any way for the binary to be aware of its own installation directory (in this case `/usr/share/weffe`) by running a command like `whereis` or accessing a shell variable?

If this is not possible, what's the best alternative? Some things I have considered are making a Makefile that manually creates a variable for the installation directory during the build process, or checking if the hard-coded `/usr/share/weffe` directory exists before trying to access files from that location. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am confused by "with data in the /usr/share/weffe folder". Are you suggesting that the weffe bin is in that directory and a link to it is in the `/usr/bin` directory? I was going to suggest that your bin/script can be made aware of the path it exists at by using the `dirname` command, e.g., `script_path="$(dirname "$0")"`

Comment: I was planning to install weffe bin in the `/usr/bin` folder and have the static files in the `/usr/share/weffe` folder. Are you saying that `dirname "$0"` can be used if everything is installed to `/usr/share/weffe` and the weffe bin file is symlinked to `/usr/bin`?

Comment: I have attempted an answer, solution, below. In the end, the script will know where to find the static resources because it is in that same directory structure. If you stick with placing the script in the bin directory and not a symlink, I think your best bet is hard coded path, find, and searching for that static directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider locating the `weffe` executable at `/usr/share/weffe/weffe-or-other-name` and then linking to it in the `bin` directory, e.g., `cd /usr/bin; ln -s ../share/weffe/weffe`.

Your script can find its location with the `dirname` command. When its a symlink, the symlink path will be returned. So, if you want to find its "real" path then you may use a combination of `dirname` and `readlink`.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Assuming you have soft linked in the bin dir.
# cd /usr/bin; ln -s ../share/weffe/weffe

# /usr/share/weffe/weffe
script_path="$(dirname "$0")"
# GNU readlink requires a -f argument.
# macOS realink does not require -f argument.
script_real_relative_path="$(readlink "$0")"
echo "script path: $script_path"
echo "script real path: $script_real_relative_path"
```